# Should a few more users vote to accept the csst tag wiki and excerpt quickly to ensure that nobody else follows my lead and rejects them?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tag-synonyms, tagging

I just saw edits for the wiki and wiki excerpt for the newly coined [csst](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csst) tag that was first added to [Details on the telescope(s) on the Chinese Space Station 天和](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43706/7982)

I reflexively rejected these edits

- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25734
- https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/25735

> The space station is not officially named the "Chinese Space Station" so the telescope is not officially named "The Chinese Space Station Telescope"

**But much to my surprise and chagrin** this naming convention has been adopted by Chinese academics:

- [Cosmology from the Chinese Space Station Optical Survey (CSS-OS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.04634)
- [Testing photometric redshift measurements with filter definition of the Chinese Space Station Optical Survey (CSS-OS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.09586)

where both Chinese Space Station Telescope or CSST, and Chinese Space Station Optical Survey or CSS-OS are used as apparently well-accepted names and acronymizations.

**Question:** I don't think I can retract my recommendations to reject those edits, so should a few more users vote to accept the [csst](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csst) tag wiki and excerpt quickly to ensure that nobody else follows my lead and rejects them?

Comment: Oops! Reading this 5 days too late...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's been done, thanks!

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags/csst/info

> Questions regarding the CSST, aka the Chinese Space Station Telescope or Xuntian.